# How to restrict access of my react build static files?

Tags: reactjs, build, react-router, create-react-app

I have created the build by `npm run build` and hosted the build folder on a server.

My problem is that I can see the static files by their paths. Eg - https://[mydomain.com]/static/js/11.ba24d9f9.chunk.js2

While if this file doesn't exist(hit a random url on this domain, eg - https://[mydomain.com]/abaknan),
it will render my 404Component because of react-router * entry.

Is it possible to block this chunk route and show 404component ?

Answer (score 1):

React is a Javascript library for UI rendering on the client-side. So, it requires all the compiled JS loaded into the document in order to render the components.

If you are using any sensitive information on your page. Please secure those in your backend application.

Comment: That I understood, but then how my other URLs are redirecting to my custom 404 pages?

I want to understand the concept behind it.

Comment: If you see the react folder structure. It has some folders in its root directory. In that, the contents of the `public` directory are served directly, whereas all other paths are being rendered in the frontend itself according to your code. Your code is compiled and stored in the js files which helps in rendering the UI in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The compiled JS chunk files are necessary to render the page. So, they must be accessible from wherever you're requesting the page. Other endpoints return your custom 404 page because the file wasn't found by React Router. Blocking chunk routes is not possible from your UI framework, you will need to add those rules on your server.